# Ubuntu disappeared from boot list order

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Ubuntu installed however I would get a path error code from grub when i tried to boot into windows.I changed the order of the boot from ubuntu to windows at the very top of the list. it worked fine and booted into windows. in order to solve the issue I turned off secure boot(as ppl mentioned that could be the issue with windows not loading from grub. however now ubuntu has completely disappeared from the bootlist. I only have the windows option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one take your liveCD/USB and open the terminal. Run these lines of code one by one.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Click recommended repair and do everything it tells you to.

Comment: great. that solved everything